# Where to place jars in Cordova app developed in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create cordova app in visual studio, because I just want to explore. I have very good idea on Cordova CLI, eclipse and Android Studio environments. My goal is to add my own custom plugin to the Visual Studio Cordova project and execute my existing code.

With the help of below link, I successfully added my custom plugin.

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/manage-plugins/#Custom

Apart from js files, my custom plugin also needs some native(android) jars, which I am going to add manually in Eclipse/Android Studio.

My problem here is - I don't find any libs folder in Visual Studio environment (as I am newbie), can some one let me know where exactly I need to required jars.